# Model memory from elf file

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, arm, elf

I am trying to model memory using Z3, however I stil have a very basic question .
Given .elf file for arm with segments and sections as shown below

```
Segments 
r-x  0x00000000-0x0000a88c 
rw-  0x0001a88c-0x0001b2dc 

Sections:
0x00008000-0x0000800c  .init (PROGBITS)  {Code}
0x0000800c-0x0000a780  .text (PROGBITS)  {Code}
0x0000a780-0x0000a78c  .fini (PROGBITS)  {Code}
0x0000a78c-0x0000a794  .rodata (PROGBITS)  {Read-only data}
0x0000a794-0x0000a7b8  .ARM.extab (PROGBITS)  {Read-only data}
0x0000a7b8-0x0000a888  .ARM.exidx  {Read-only data}
0x0000a888-0x0000a88c  .eh_frame (PROGBITS)  {Read-only data}
0x0001a88c-0x0001a894  .init_array  {Writable data}
0x0001a894-0x0001a898  .fini_array  {Writable data}
0x0001a898-0x0001a89c  .jcr (PROGBITS)  {Writable data}
0x0001a8a0-0x0001b0e0  .data (PROGBITS)  {Writable data}
0x0001b0e0-0x0001b2dc  .bss (NOBITS)  {Writable data}
```

If I have instrution like Load R3, [R0] with R0 = 0
Where can I found the zero memory location to load its initial value in the elf file i.e M[0] ?
How can I model the memory values before execution ? For example, I would like to have
address range like from 0xaaaa  to 0xcccc in elf files are M[0] to M[final] initial values.

Comment: what is M[0] mean?  If you want the code to be in that address space then link it that way, this appears to be linked for 0x8000.

Comment: In my model, the memory is modeled as map (address+ value) , so M[0] means the first value in the memory model at adress 0xaaaaaa which is modeled in my model as start address 0